# Given $v\in T_pM$ there exists $(U, \varphi)$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\bigg\rvert_p = v $

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM\ v \neq 0$ show there exists a smooth chart $(U, \varphi=(x_1,\dots,x_n))$ such that: $p \in U$ and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\bigg\rvert_p = v
$$

Even more this can be generalized to given any linearly independet set $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ in $T_pM$ there exists a smooth chart $(U, \varphi=(x_1,\dots,x_n))$ such that: $p \in U$ and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\bigg\rvert_p = v_1 ,\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\bigg\rvert_p = v_2\ , ...,\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\bigg\rvert_p = v_k  
$$

any help in solving this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove that, in $\Bbb R^n$, there is a diffeomorphism  $\varphi$ with $d_0\varphi(e_i)= v_i$ for any given basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$?

Comment: My above comment may contain an unnecessary trap, so here is another hint: linear isomorphisms are diffeomorphisms

Comment: Yes I can do it. I think $\varphi = v_1x_1 + \dots + v_nx_n$ works

Comment: Now, compose your chart $U\to \Bbb R^n$ with a suitable linear map to solve the problem

Comment: I got the idea. Now I'm going to write the complete proof. Thank you !

Comment: @TomásSentagne If you have the complete proof, you should write it down in form of an official answer to your own question.